# How to print QR code in Yii2?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2

I want to print QR code image with this source:

```
<img class="qrCode" src="<?=Url::to(['site/qrcode', 'code' => $model->id])?>"/>
```

Controller:

```
public function actionQrcode($code) {
 return QrCode::jpg($code);
}
```

[image]

but in print page, image dose't show.

[image]

Js code:

```
        function printDiv(el) {
            var restorepage = document.body.innerHTML;
            var printcontent = document.getElementById(el).innerHTML;
            document.body.innerHTML = printcontent;
            window.print();
            document.body.innerHTML = restorepage;
        }
```

Comment: What site/qrcode action returns?

Comment: this is action link: mysite.com/site/qrcode?code=1463166327 And in returns: something like this '���u^�l@�+ѱK��|�$R�)}ճt�?���6V$p)��4=�H�R#�u�C��~�܃���-]��|��g��ΨB3�ˊ��(�iFnd��8b�lPT���=�ݲf����4�ψ\S4��r�=�tc��é�k����s�?���{�k�������zIEND�B`�'

Comment: Could be it returns file content instead filename?

Comment: public function actionQrcode($code) {
        return QrCode::jpg($code);
    } it returns file content

Comment: It's better if you edit the question and add the code

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a problem of Yii2, i think the problem is in your JS.

I can guess few variants:

1. `$('.qrCode').attr("src", '<?= Url::to(['site/qrcode', 'code' => $model->id]) ?>');` - are you sure that row works fine? I mean it's really changes the SRC of your image .qrCode? And URL is correct?
2. If line of code works fine, i think the problem is because image doesn't load in time before window.print triggers. So my suggestion, is to change the code:

```js
function printDiv(el) {
  var qrImage = new Image();
  // wait 'till image loads
  qrImage.onload= function() {
    var restorepage = document.body.innerHTML;
    var printcontent = document.getElementById(el).innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = printcontent;
    $('.qrCode').attr("src", qrImage.src);
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = restorepage;
  }
  qrImage.src = '<?= Url::to(['site/qrcode', 'code' => $model->id]) ?>'; 
}
```

Comment: this line work fine "$('.qrCode').attr("src", '<?= Url::to(['site/qrcode', 'code' => $model->id]) ?>');", but not working  on print.

Comment: As i sad, may be image doesn't load in time before print, can you try second variant?

Comment: I mean is not js, the image load on this code: <img class="qrCode" src="<?=Url::to(['site/qrcode', 'code' => $model->id])?>"/>, but dose't load on printing

Comment: So, why did you add JS code there in your example? I thought you trigger print with `printDiv` function

Comment: The image creating by qrcode actions, the problem is when i want to print page , image dose't show!

Comment: How do you print page? With JS function `printDiv` or just with Ctrl+P?

Comment: With JS function printDiv

Comment: Oh, you have changed your post and JS example *___*

So, if that, problem can be in CSS rule and media (print), some rule can hide image from print version

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to print QR Code data

```
              $image = Yii::$app->params['BASE_URL'] . 'abc.png';
              $qrcode = new \Zxing\QrReader($image);
              $text = $qrcode->text();
```